# Page Permalinks: Custom URLs

Tags: customization, url-rewriting, urls, static-website

I'm trying to make URLs that have different "routes", per say. I don't know how to explain it, but on the site I had to move, the owners want it to have different suburl URL directories. Problem is, I don't have the foggiest idea as to what it's even called, or how the guy previously achieved this.

Customers are used to seeing it in this form, so they want to keep it as:

```
www.example.com/suburl/page-name
www.example.com/suburl2/page-name
```

The part I speak of is the "suburl" section of the examples above... the rest of the site links the way it should. These are just static pages, which I did confirm.

**Edit:** After looking at the code for a couple hours, I realized that the last guy made a blank page as a "parent", and the children were the slugs. But what I do not understand is how the relationship was broken from moving the site to a new server. Any advice?

Thank you guys!

Kudos to Michael Rogers for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question isn't very clear to me but i'll attempt to answer anyway, forgive me if it's obvious to you:

What you describe is the behavior of "custom post types" When you create custom post types you define a slug like your "suburl" and "suburl2" and all posts created under that type fall under site.com/suburl/post-title

I'm sure that if you first create the necessary post types and then change the type of each post to fall under the proper type you can achieve that structure.

Comment: Hi Michael!
I just figured out what the last guy had done (I'll adjust my question so it's proper to my issue).

He made a blank page as a "category", and then just made children after it..... so /suburl/ was actually a parent. I don't understand why they are no longer linking.

Comment: Have you tried going to Settings -> Permalinks and using a Custom Structure like: /%category%/%postname%/

Comment: Hi Michael, I did. I'm using pages... so it did not work. I did some research, and it said that categories could not apply to pages.

Thanks for everything!